# Express + Sequelize: hanging the app on connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I have an app with postgres as db, sequelize, and express, and whenever it receives a db query, it just stays there forever, no logging or anything
I run postgres in a container which I can connect to through GUI normally
When I swapped it for sqlite, it worked perfectly the application

here is the relevant piece of code

```js
const databaseURL =
  process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
  "postgres://postgres:postgres@0.0.0.0:5432/postgres";
console.log(databaseURL)
const db = new Sequelize(databaseURL, { logging: console.log });
```

on docker compose

```
dc ps            
       Name                     Command              State                    Ports                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
baity-backend_db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp,:::5432->5432/tcp
```

logs

```
> DEBUG=express:* node index.js

  express:application set "x-powered-by" to true +0ms
  express:application set "etag" to 'weak' +1ms
  express:application set "etag fn" to [Function: generateETag] +1ms
  express:application set "env" to 'development' +0ms
  express:application set "query parser" to 'extended' +1ms
  express:application set "query parser fn" to [Function: parseExtendedQueryString] +0ms
  express:application set "subdomain offset" to 2 +0ms
  express:application set "trust proxy" to false +0ms
  express:application set "trust proxy fn" to [Function: trustNone] +0ms
  express:application booting in development mode +0ms
  express:application set "view" to [Function: View] +0ms
  express:application set "views" to '/home/omar/workspace/js/baity-backend/views' +0ms
  express:application set "jsonp callback name" to 'callback' +0ms
postgres://postgres:postgres@0.0.0.0:5432/postgres
```

**Update 1:**

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
    env_file:
      - ./frontend/.env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/opt/web
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
        - .:/code
        - /code/node_modules
    restart: always
    command: npm start
    env_file:
      - .env
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11.14-bullseye
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./.data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

```
FROM node:14.18.2-bullseye

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node based server for real eastate website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "xxx <xxx@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "cloudinary": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-form-data": "^2.0.12",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.5",
    "sequelize-auto-migrations": "^1.0.3",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
    "stripe": "^8.35.0"
  }
}
```

**node:** 14.18.2

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres
```

Comment: All these inside one container , or different containers, attach your Dockerfile or docker-compose.

Comment: post your package.json file and Node.JS Version

Comment: @madflow done @ yassine done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick test: according to your posted `package.json` -  you are using an incompatible version of the `pg` module and Node.Js 14.

See [this issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180) for more context.

The solution is: make sure you are running the latest `pg` version.

For example with yarn:

```
yarn add pg@"8.7.1"
```

If this is not possible for any reason - downgrading to Node 12 should also work. This can be easily tested in your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your "0.0.0.0:5432".

If local, it should be just "localhost:5432".
If deployed server is remote, it should be a certain IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5432.
If deployed server is home network, it should be "192.168.0.XXX:5432".

Check your postgres network configuration
https://youtu.be/Erqp4C3Y3Ds

Comment: I'm on local, and I can connect with DBeaver with the same credentials, host, pass
I also made a new container and tested the connection with hostname db (container name) instead, and still fails

Answer (score 0):

In the node.js container when trying to connect to the database it will try to connect to itself "0.0.0.0" on port 5432 where there is no Postgres running. Assuming you have a container for nodejs backend app, and postgres instance for database.
You need to guide the nodejs container where's the Postgres instance.

You need to change the host `"0.0.0.0:5432"` to your `docker-name`.

In your case, you can change that variable databaseURL or set variable DATABASE_URL
to "`postgresql://postgres:postgres@your_machine_ip:5432/postgres`"

As you're using docker-compose:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: app-database
    network: postgres
    image: postgres
    ...

  express:
    container_name: app-backend
    network: postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@app-database:5432/postgres"

  networks:
    postgres:
      driver: bridge

    ...
```

as you can see the DATABASE_URL will use the "app-database" which is the name of postgres container.

Comment: done that with host db, still nothing new

Comment: @OmarS. check if you are using the correct network driver. I've included that in the update answer.

Comment: also tried that but no joy